# can't get mod_proxy to correctly forward encoded slash (/) characters (%2f)

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a virtual host set up to redirect `ntung-gitblit.localhost` --> `myserver:1279`. However, it's not working with forward encoded slashes (`%2f`). The URL I'm trying to access is,

```
http://ntung-gitblit.localhost/ABC%2fXYZ
```

Without `AllowEncodedSlashes`, it fails -- apache tries to access `/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var` on the server. Setting `AllowEncodedSlashes` to `On` results in the following internal URL hit,

```
http://myserver:1279/ABC/XYZ
```

And setting `AllowEncodedSlashes` to `NoDecode` results in the following URL being hit,

```
http://myserver:1279/ABC%252fXYZ
```

In other, words, it's over-escaping or under-escaping. **Question**: How do I make it hit `myserver:1279/ABC%2fXYZ`?

Answer (score 19):

Sorry, just got it (3rd answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390436/need-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache)), the solution is to use `nocanon` in the `ProxyPass` directive,

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
ProxyPass / http://myserver:1279/ nocanon
```

I can delete the question if it's no longer helpful.

Comment: Thanks for not being DenverCooper9. https://xkcd.com/979/